# JsonGenerator not working with non english content

Tags: java, json, jackson, fasterxml

I am trying to write arabic content through `JsonGenerator`. Everytime it produces wired characters -

```
??????
```

Or

```
Ø£ÙˆÙ…ÙŠØºØ§
```

Howerver it should produce `أوميغا`

#### Code Snippet

```
OutputStream jsonOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
JsonGenerator generator = new JsonFactory().createGenerator(jsonOutput, JsonEncoding.UTF8);
generator.writeStartObject();
jsonOutput.write("أوميغا".getBytes());
generator.writeEndObject();
generator.close();
```

Comment: What is the Java version and OS you are using. Because I tried the same code you gave and it worked for me. I was able to print the Arabic value

Comment: Windows 10 and java version "1.8.0_191"

Comment: Weird, Im using Windows 10 with 1.8.0_151. I just printed value of `jsonOutput System.out.println("jsonOutput: "+jsonOutput);` and it prints the value correctly.

Comment: I'd try adding the charset to getBytes method `jsonOutput.write("أوميغا".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`

Comment: You should only write data through the JsonGenerator, not directly through the OutputStream.  And a string by itself in a JSON object is invalid JSON.  You probably want something like `generator.write("value", "أوميغا");`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Windows, ANSI on Arabic Windows is `ANSI-1256`

You should translate it to unicode and then use it to prevent errors.